# printing all the characters at once, objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nslog

I have a question regarding printing of characters
Suppose, the output of a program is
a
b
c
d
How do i print all of them at once on the output line? and if I need to output that in a particular label field on iphone, how can that be done?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can construct an `NSString` using your program's output and log it or use it for the label's text?

```
// Assuming the variable a, b, c, and d contain your program's output.
NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", a, b, c, d];
```

Comment: actually those are the examples of the output of the for-loop for    
char z = x ^ c;  I tried your method to print out "z". But it is showing me an error. below is the error thats popping up

Comment: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all

Comment: If you want your output as a single line, you need to construct a string and use that string (using `NSMutableString` if need be). I'm guessing you're getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error because `a`, `b`, etc. aren't objects.  See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943